# What are the requirements for a Kerberos realm name?

Tags: kerberos

Every example I have seen so far of a valid Kerberos realm name is of the form "example.com". None of the pages I have read give the actual naming rules.

What are the naming rules?

Must a Kerberos realm be named with a TLD or a dot-plus-extension?

Or, can a Kerberos realm be named with a single word without any dot-plus-extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MIT Kerberos documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.14/doc/admin/realm_config.html) says:

> #### Realm name
>
> Although your Kerberos realm can be any ASCII string, convention is to
>   make it the same as your domain name, in upper-case letters.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E37126/kplanning-27.html):

Kerberos Realm Names

> Realm names can consist of any ASCII string. Usually, the realm name
>   is the same as your DNS domain name except that the realm name is in
>   uppercase. This convention helps differentiate problems with the
>   Kerberos service from problems with the DNS namespace, while keeping a
>   name that is familiar. You can use any string, but configuration and
>   maintenance might then require more work. Use realm names that follow
>   the standard Internet naming structure.